# Printing the content of array slots in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Hi i am trying to finsih an assignment in C# but i am stuck 
my problem is that i cant get the information from from my array to print out in the right order 
some of this code is in Swedish but i hope you understand,

I want the print to be 
for example :

*Number of sales men on level 1 : 2
Name : Bert *
"" and the rest of the information
and then when all the sales men on that level are printed the salesmen on the next level and so on

Antal säljare på nivå 1 : 2
Namn : Bert

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
            public struct Säljare // skapar en construkt för säljare.
        {
            public String Namn;
            public String Personnummer;
            public String Distrikt;
            public int AntalArtiklar;
            public int Niva;

        }
                // skapar en array för bubblesort
            private static void BubbleSort(Säljare[] osorterad)
            {
                int length = osorterad.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < length - 1 - i; j++)
                    {
                        if (osorterad[j].AntalArtiklar > osorterad[j + 1].AntalArtiklar)
                        {
                            Säljare num = osorterad[j];
                            osorterad[j] = osorterad[j + 1];
                            osorterad[j + 1] = num;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int counter = 0;        // skapar variablar till nivåerna och en counter
                int nivaett = 0;
                int nivatva = 0;
                int nivatre = 0;
                int nivafyra = 0;
                Säljare[] Säljkår = new Säljare[6];
                Säljare[] osorterad = new Säljare[6];



                System.Console.WriteLine("Ange säljare och resultat:");
            // låter personer skriva in 6 personer och dess attribut
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // Läs in alla säljare i en array av "Säljare"
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("\nAnge information för säljare " + (i + 1));
                    System.Console.Write("Ange Namn: ");
                    Säljkår[i].Namn = System.Console.ReadLine();
                    System.Console.Write("Ange Personnummer: ");
                    Säljkår[i].Personnummer = System.Console.ReadLine();
                    System.Console.Write("Ange Distrikt: ");
                    Säljkår[i].Distrikt = System.Console.ReadLine();
                    System.Console.Write("Ange antal Artiklar: ");
                    Säljkår[i].AntalArtiklar = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

                    // lägger till i varje nivå
                    if (Säljkår[i].AntalArtiklar < 50)

                        Säljkår[counter].Niva = 1;
                        nivaett++;


                    if (Säljkår[i].AntalArtiklar >= 50 && Säljkår[i].AntalArtiklar < 100)

                        Säljkår[counter].Niva = 2;
                        nivatva++;


                    if (Säljkår[i].AntalArtiklar >= 100 && Säljkår[i].AntalArtiklar < 200)

                        Säljkår[counter].Niva = 3;
                        nivatre++;


                    if (Säljkår[i].AntalArtiklar > 200)

                        Säljkår[counter].Niva = 4;
                        nivafyra++;




                }

                BubbleSort(Säljkår); // sorterar arrayen säljkår



               // skriver ut varje person sorterad efter antal artiklar

               // for (counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++) 
              //  {
                   // Console.WriteLine("");
                  //  Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + Säljkår[counter].Namn);
                   // Console.WriteLine("Personnummer: " + Säljkår[counter].Personnummer);
                   // Console.WriteLine("Distrikt: " + Säljkår[counter].Distrikt);
                 //   Console.WriteLine("Antal sälj: " + Säljkår[counter].AntalArtiklar);
                 //   Console.WriteLine("Sälj Nivå: " + Säljkår[counter].Niva);
                   // Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");


              //  }
                // skriver ut uppnåda nivåer och antal



            Console.WriteLine("Antal Säljare på nivå 1 : " + nivaett);




            Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + Säljkår[counter].Namn);
            Console.WriteLine("Personnummer: " + Säljkår[counter].Personnummer);
            Console.WriteLine("Distrikt: " + Säljkår[counter].Distrikt);
            Console.WriteLine("Antal sälj: " + Säljkår[counter].AntalArtiklar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sälj Nivå: " + Säljkår[counter].Niva);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");


                Console.WriteLine("Antal Säljare på nivå 2 : " + nivatva);


                Console.WriteLine("Antal Säljare på nivå 3 : " +nivatre);


                Console.WriteLine("Antal Säljare på nivå 4 : " + nivafyra);

                Console.ReadLine();


            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably a good thing to at least have code comments in English when posting here. While I understand Swedish, most users here don't.

Comment: Please clearly explain your problem, especially, explain how the code does not match your expectations. Furthermore, only show the relevant code, this wall of code will likely earn you a lot of downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want to write all the information in array. for that you need to use a loop like this

```
for(int i=0;i<Säljkår.Length;i++)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + Säljkår[i].Namn);
      Console.WriteLine("Personnummer: " + Säljkår[i].Personnummer);
      Console.WriteLine("Distrikt: " + Säljkår[i].Distrikt);
      Console.WriteLine("Antal sälj: " + Säljkår[i].AntalArtiklar);
      Console.WriteLine("Sälj Nivå: " + Säljkår[i].Niva);
      Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
}
```